# How to change the default background color in `tabularray` package in LaTeX?

Tags: tabularray

I make a lot of table in my tex file and I want to change all the table's background color to RGB{245,246,246}. Is there a way to change all the tables' background color to that? What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\SetTblrInner` command to make default settings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myback}{RGB}{245,246,246}
\SetTblrInner[tblr]{cells={bg=myback}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{hlines}
  Alpha & Beta \\
  Delta & Gamma
\end{tblr}

\bigskip

\begin{tblr}{hlines}
  Alpha & Beta \\
  Delta & Gamma
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, it is no use in `talltblr` environment. Why?

Comment: @Y.zeng Add `\SetTblrInner[talltblr]{cells={bg=myback}}` line. Please always give an minimal example in your question so that others know what you reallly want.

Comment: Is there a way to set `tblr`, `talltblr` and `longtblr` together? I tested these codes `\SetTblrInner[talltblr,tblr,longtblr]{cells={bg=tablebackground}}`, but failed.

Comment: @Y.zeng No at this time. But I am thinking to add `\SetTblrInner*{<settings>}` for changing settings of all `tabularray` environments to the package, see this issue https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/37

Comment: Thanks. Now I need to `\SetTblrInner[tblr]{}`,  `\SetTblrInner[talltblr]{}` and  `\SetTblrInner[longtblr]{}` seperately. Am I right?

Comment: @Y.zeng Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thanks so very. Have a nice day ahead!